# Food in hand luggage

Tags: air-travel, food-and-drink, hand-luggage

I'm flying with Ryanair soon, and would like to take a small amount of food with me in my hand luggage. In general, what are the rules/restrictions on this? I know that there might be some safety issues concerning on-board security, the risk of carrying diseases, etc.

Some types of food that I'm thinking of:

- Home made snacks (cakes, etc);
- Bread / sandwiches;
- Food in sealed container;
- Food in a container that has already been opened.

Is there a list of guidelines that I should be aware of, to ensure that I'll be able to take everything with me on-board?

Comment: I always bring my own food when travelling low cost. Sometimes even on standard flights as the quality of the food served on-board is getting worse and worse. You can even bring water/juice/liquids in general. Obviously you'll have to buy these after baggage check.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44451/practical-food-to-take-on-flight-without-anything-served

Comment: To / from what country?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[According to Ryanair](http://www.ryanair.com/en/questions/can-i-bring-my-own-food-onboard/), you are welcome to do so.
As for diseases etc., the regulations usually regard meat and dairy products, but if you are traveling within EU, [you are ok](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/carry/meat-dairy-animal/index_en.htm). Outside, however, it depends on the country.

In my experience, ham and cheese sandwiches have never been a problem on European flights, including those with Ryanair. As long as it is not liquid (see Edit) you shouldn't have any issues getting it through security and on board.

Edit:
Gathering the comments on non-obviously liquid items that will/may cause problems at security gates:

- Yogurt (no matter how dense)
- Jam/Marmalade
- Tinned fish (in oil)
- Honey
- Purees
- Butter
- Peanut butter

Apparently fruits are OK (but not too juicy/mushy? ;))

Comment: Note that jam/marmalade is also considered too liquid to be taken on board, I know from personal experience.

Comment: Cans are also frowned upon.  I've had a 125g tin of sprats (fish) in oil confiscated, because oil is a liquid and liquids are bad.

Comment: However, I can add from personal experience that fruit & veggies seem to be OK, but they look like liquids to the x-ray scanner. So take them out before getting your carry-on bag scanned to avoid delays.

Comment: Just remember that some security agents have a very wide definition of 'liquid'. During the last year, I have been releived from honey, chestnut puree and butter in the security checks at European airports.

Comment: I had a jar of peanut butter confiscated, so creamy products are out too. Unless already spread on the bread.

Comment: Some sausages can also look like liquids to the x-ray operator. I've once had to open my bag to show a chorizo. I was allowed to keep it, though.

Comment: (+1) In fact, it's simpler than that, the restriction is not limited to liquids but concerns “liquids, aerosols and gels”, which is obviously broader.

Comment: Are ice cubes liquid? :-)

Comment: @Gnubie Completely frozen liquids are allowed, but partly melted ones are not.  (Yes, that does not make any sense.) https://apps.tsa.dhs.gov/mytsa/cib_results.aspx?search=gel%20ice%20pack

Comment: jam, marmelade, etc. while considered gels or liquids when in their packaging should not be a problem if you use them to make a sandwich you then pack in your lunch box and take with you that way. Same way that a jar of apple chutney isn't allowed, but slice of apple pie is. Or a jar of mayonaise is illegal but a bowl of salad with a blob of mayonaise in it is. The main problem with food is always getting it through security at arrival, not departure, as many countries have very strict rules against importing food from almost anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

The website of [RyanAir](http://www.ryanair.com/en/questions/can-i-bring-my-own-food-onboard/) states that food is okay to bring.

I would suggest using a plastic bag or plastic container, instead of a metal container shaped as a bomb, but I guess that's pretty obvious. And there won't be any safety risks if you bring regular food like bread/sandwiches/etc.

You can't bring drinks through the security check, however you can buy drinks afterwards to take on your flight.

Comment: Or bring an empty water bottle and refill after security.

Comment: @jpatokal Never even thought about that, nice thinking ;)

Comment: @jpatokal Definitely an empty water bottle. Just tell the security people it's empty and, in my experience, they're completely happy. I once forgot to mention it and, even then, nothing happened. Many airports have taps/water fountains that you can use to refill a bottle: they're ubiquitous in the US but often harder to find in Europe.

Comment: In AMS I could refill my bottle for Schengen flights, but not for non-Schengen. In DUS and FRA I successfully refilled my bottle before international flights as well, but AMS still has at-gate security. Renovations for the switch to centralized security are underway.

Comment: @Alexander: I took a non-Schengen (UK) flight from AMS last year. I must have got lucky with the "underway" part of what you said, since my gate was one of a group of maybe 4 that shared security. There was a coffee/sandwich shop and I think a water fountain airside, so no problem. I suppose with a good source of information, you can figure out your options once you have your gate.

Comment: Note that while "You can't bring drinks through the security check, however you can buy drinks afterwards to take on your flight."  may be safe in this case, in some instances they perform a second security check at the boarding gate and will (again) confiscate any liquids at that point - even those just bought and unopened. I have seen this happen on several occasions. QANTAS tend to do this in Asia (amd maybe elsewhere) but they are not the only ones.

Comment: AMS has three different systems running side by side, security at the start of the 'secure zone', security for groups of gates, and security at the gate. Some country destinations seem to have gate security, US and Israel if I say from memory, other countries might have either kind. Even when your US flight leaves from an area with one security check at passport control, you might still have a gate check extra.

Comment: Refilling your water bottle from the cold tap in the toilet on level 2 in the Eiffel tower can lead you to being physically assaulted by the (oldish, female) attendant (ask me how I know) but seems less liable to be a problem with Ryan Air, even if only because the time taken may divert them from getting passengers on on on! and off off off off !!!!  ... the aircraft.