# Can I take a 330g tin of Fois Gras Poitiers in my 10 kg cabin bag with Ryanair?

Tags: food-and-drink, hand-luggage, ryanair, prohibited-items, stn

Can I take a 330g tin of Fois Gras Poitiers in my 10 kg cabin bag from France to London Stansted with Ryanair?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the answers of the question "[Food in hand luggage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46573/food-in-hand-luggage)" *tinned food* is usually not allowed as there is liquid in the tin. Even tinned tuna in oil has been denied.

If you want you could try to take it with you, but be prepared to fly without it.

I'd put it in the same tray as the phone and liquids, clearly visible.

Comment: If fois gras is spreadable, which I think it is, it is not allowed in hand luggage over 100 ml, which this will be.